# Linear Algebra - Dual vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is:

''In this problem, we shall explore some if the concepts surrounding dual vector spaces for the specific case of $V= P(3)$, the vector space of polynomials with real coeficients of degree less than or equal to $3$. Assume through that $V=P(3)$

a) Describe a basis for $V^*$ (dual vector space) and express the linear functional $f:V\to R$ given by: $$f(a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0)=2a_3+a_1-5a_0$$ as a linear combination of the basis you found for $V^*$.

b) Find a basis for the annihilator $W$ of the subspace $W= \text{span}(1+x^2, x+x^3)$ which belongs to $C$. What's dimension of annihilator of $W$?

c) We know that the evaluation map $E:V\to V^{**}$ is a vector space isomorphism. Then $E(x^2+x^3)$  is a linear functional on $V^*$. What is the value of the linear functional $E(x^2+x^3)$ on the linear functional $f$ from part (a) ? (I.e, what is $E(x^2+x^3)(f)$?''
Please help me ! I even don't know how to start !

Comment: I reformatted your question. Please check and make sure that I didn't change what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Well, the very beginning is to write a basis for $V$.

Comment: For 1) since f(a3x^3+a2x^2+a1x+a0)= 2a3+a1-5a0 is a linear combination of 2x^3+x-5 so P(3)= span{-5,x,2x^3} which is mine basis for V ( B={-5,x,2x^3}, so then V* has basis B*={-5*,x*,2x^3*} am I correct ? and if yes how can I express the linear function f:V->R as a linear combination of the basis ?

Comment: Actually i was thinking about it again, and what i did i choosed B={e0,e1,e3} where e0=1,e1=x,e3=x^3 and B*={e0*,e1*,e3*}. since f[a0,a1,a2,a,3] as a column matrix is equal to 2a3+a1-5a0 I can express this as a linear combination of 2e3*+e1*-5e0*. Am i correct ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll give some hints for you to get started:

1. If $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space with basis $B$, then there's a natural choice for a basis $B^\ast$ in the space $V^\ast$ which is the *dual basis* how can you use this?
2. Recall that the annihilator of $ W \subset V$ is the set of all $f \in V^\ast$ such that $f(w)=0$ for all $w \in W$. It seems you *know* a basis for $W$ agree? So, use the definition!
3. Write down explicitly the evaluation map and apply it. Example: if we take $x \in P(3)$, then the evaluation $E: V \to V^{\ast\ast}$ is $E(x)(f) = f(x)$.

If you need further aid ask in comment.

Comment: For 1)  since f(a3x^3+a2x^2+a1x+a0)= 2a3+a1-5a0 is a linear combination of 2x^3+x-5 so P(3)= span{-5,x,2x^3} which is mine basis for V ( B={-5,x,2x^3}, so then V* has basis B*={-5*,x*,2x^3*} am I correct ? and if yes how can I express the linear function f:V->R as a linear combination of the basis ?

Comment: The answer would have been nice. I'd like to know what the basis for the dual is! Giving the answer (but not the workings) would have been perfect.

Comment: A "standard" $ \{\delta_i^j\}$ dual basis is given by functions that are $1$ on the i-th basis element and are otherwise $0$
  As a worked example, say we have the basis $\{ (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ then the dual basis $ \delta_i^j; i,j=1,2,3 $ for it's dual would be one so that $\delta_1^1(1,0,0)=1 ; \delta_1^2 (0,1,0)=0 ; \delta_1^3(0,0,1)=0; \delta_2^1(1,0,0)=0; \delta_2^2(0,1,0)=1, etc$; here, the Projections $P_i$ is the projection into the $i-$th coordinate, so that, e.g., $P_1(1,0,0)=1, P_1(0,1,0)=P_1(0,0,1)=0$

Start with that and then we can complete the rest.